# How to set plutus-apps NixOS options on Mac

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix, nixos

This is the first time I've used nix. On plutus-apps readme, I changed nix.conf but I don't know how to do this step.

2.On NixOS, set the following NixOS options:

nix = {
binaryCaches          = [ "https://hydra.iohk.io" "https://iohk.cachix.org" ];
binaryCachePublicKeys = [ "hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ=" "iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo=" ];
};

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an M1 Mac follow these instructions https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1/blob/main/README.md

You should probably uninstall Nix first though (scroll to the bottom of that page to get a script for an easier uninstall)

Answer (score 1):

I followed steps 4-6 in https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html and those worked for me (I have an Intel Mac - Big Sur). You could try them and see if they work for you. Those steps are:

Step 4. Edit the /etc/nix/nix.conf file:

`nano /etc/nix/nix.conf`

note, you will have to create that file if it doesn't exist

Step 5 - Add these lines to the file:

```
substituters = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj
```

Step 6 - Restart your computer - important that you do this

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].